# belongs_to through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given the following associations, I need to reference the `Question` that a `Choice` is attached through from the `Choice` model. I have been attempting to use `belongs_to :question, through: :answer` to perform this action.

```
class User
  has_many :questions
  has_many :choices
end

class Question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
  has_one :choice, :through => :answer
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end

class Choice
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :question, :through => :answer

  validates_uniqueness_of :answer_id, :scope => [ :question_id, :user_id ]
end
```

I am getting

> NameError uninitialized constant `User::Choice`

when I try to do `current_user.choices`

It works fine, if I don't include the

```
belongs_to :question, :through => :answer
```

But I want to use that because I want to be able to do the `validates_uniqueness_of`

I am probably overlooking something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's worth changing the accepted answer to the delegate one?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A `belongs_to` association cannot have a `:through` option. You're better off caching the `question_id` on `Choice` and adding a unique index to the table (especially because `validates_uniqueness_of` is prone to race conditions).

If you're paranoid, add a custom validation to `Choice` that confirms that the answer's `question_id` matches, but it sounds like the end user should never be given the opportunity to submit data that would create this kind of mismatch.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I really didn't want to have to associate directly with question_id, but I guess its the easiest way.

My original thought was, since "answer" belongs to "question", I can always go through "answer" to get to the "question". But do you think thats not easy to do, or do you think thats just a bad schema?

Comment: If you want a unique constraint/validations, the scoped fields must exist in the same table. Remember, there are race conditions.

Comment: >> it sounds like the end user should never be given the opportunity to submit data that would create this kind of mismatch. --

You never can guarantee that the user "does not have an opportunity to do something" unless you do an explicit server-side check for that.

Answer (score 430):

You can also delegate:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :dogs, :through => :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRescord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  delegate :company, :to => :employee, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Comment: +1, this is the cleanest way to do this. (at least that i can think)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with JOIN so that it doesn't use so many queries?

Comment: I'd like to know myself. Everything I tried fired 3 selects. You can specify a "-> { joins :something }" lambda on an association. The join is fired but subsequently another select anyway. I wasn't able to tune this up.

Comment: @Tallboy A few perfectly indexed select queries on primary keys are almost always better than any single JOIN query. Joins make the database work hard.

Comment: What does the allow_nil do? Shouldn't an Employee always have a company?

Comment: @affinities23 : That depends on your particular requirements. You might want "volatile" employees without any company. However here the allow_nil thing means that if ```dog.employee``` is nil then the call to ```dog.company``` will not fail and just return nil as well. Even if you always want these things to be required, it's good to have this, because you can always just go to the rails console and type ```dog = Dog.new```. At that point you have a non-presistent record and you can still do ```dog.company``` without any failure.

Comment: I disagree with the three trips across the network being better than a single join.  Like three trips to the local store is better than one.. No matter how close the store it is still better to go to cross the "street" once.

Comment: Going once is always better but the trips are not the only issue. Imagine you go to the store once but you request something that the storekeeper has to get from his warehouse. So you have to wait for him to get it for you. Or you can ask only for things that he has handy and can give to you right away - but you have to go multiple times. Not a very good analogy, I know, but I cannot do any better right now :-). I think if you're really after perf, you must measure your particular case. I have done that, firing three selects was faster than firing a single complicated JOIN.

Comment: But if you were, say, in South Africa and your db server was an amazon-rented server in Ireland, than the latency of the trips would likely be a greater issue and then using joins would be faster.

Comment: @Tallboy Proper Although you'd need at least three selects, proper use of `includes` to eager-load should ensure you'd need at _most_ three selects as well.

Comment: mongodb does not like it

Comment: First time hearing of delegate. Is it possible to explain it a little in the answer? (I could copy the code and adjust it, but would not necessarily understand it)

Comment: People have already done a much better job at that, then I could here. For example: https://medium.com/@pk60905/using-delegate-in-rails-527332da7f96

Answer (score 156):

Just use `has_one` instead of `belongs_to` in your `:through`, like this:

```rb
class Choice
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  has_one :question, :through => :answer
end
```

Unrelated, but I'd be hesitant to use validates_uniqueness_of instead of using a proper unique constraint in your database. When you do this in ruby you have race conditions.

Comment: Big warning with this solution. Whenever you save Choice it will always save Question unless `autosave: false` is set.

Comment: @ChrisNicola can you please explain what you meant, I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: What I meant where? If you mean a proper unique constraint, I mean adding a UNIQUE index to the column/field that must be unique in the database.

Comment: Smart answer actually

Comment: Also `delegate` (suggested in another question) seems to first load `answer` and then `question`. `has_one` uses active record and creates a join query, so it uses one query less.

Answer (score 3):

My approach was to make a virtual attribute instead of adding database columns.

```
class Choice
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer

  # ------- Helpers -------
  def question
    answer.question
  end

  # extra sugar
  def question_id
    answer.question_id
  end
end
```

This approach is pretty simple, but comes with tradeoffs.  It requires Rails to load `answer` from the db, and then `question`.  This can be optimized later by eager loading the associations you need (i.e. `c = Choice.first(include: {answer: :question})`), however, if this optimization is necessary, then stephencelis' answer is probably a better performance decision.

There's a time and place for certain choices, and I think this choice is better when prototyping.  I wouldn't use it for production code unless I knew it was for an infrequent use case.

Answer (score 3):

So you cant have the behavior that you want but you can do something that feels like it. You want to be able to do `Choice.first.question`

what I have done in the past is something like this

```
class Choice
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  validates_uniqueness_of :answer_id, :scope => [ :question_id, :user_id ]
  ...
  def question
    answer.question
  end
end
```

this way the you can now call question on **Choice**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a User who has many Questions.
The Question has many Answers, one of which is the User's Choice.

Is this what you are after?

I would model something like that along these lines:

```
class User
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :answers
  has_one    :choice, :class_name => "Answer"

  validates_inclusion_of :choice, :in => lambda { answers }
end

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `has_many :choices` creates an association named `choices`, not `choice`. Try using `current_user.choices` instead.

See the [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) documentation for information about about the `has_many` magic.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, however, thats a typo on my part. I am already doing current_user.choices. This error has something to do with me wanting to assign belongs_to to user and question.