# many to many in active record not returning value in one direction; duplicates in the other

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to set up a simple domain to practice getting better at modeling Ruby relationships.  In this, an author can have many books, but a book can only have one author.  Books have many characters, which can appear in multiple books.  That works fine.  It's the Author to Character relationship that I'm struggling with.  When I try to access `character.author` I get `nil`.  `author.characters` returns a list with duplicates--seven Harry Potters, one for each book.  Ideally I'd want `rowling.characters` to return a list of just one Harry Potter (we're not fleeing Privet Drive) and obviously `harry.author` to return the instance of JK Rowling.

author.rb

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :books
    has_many :characters, through: :books

end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :author
    has_and_belongs_to_many :characters
end
```

character.rb

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :books
    belongs_to :author, through: :books
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_06_18_134335) do

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "pen_name"
  end

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "author_id"
  end

  create_table "books_characters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "book_id"
    t.integer "character_id"
  end

  create_table "characters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "author_id"
  end

end
```

Comment: Why must a character belong to one author? The character could be in two books, written by different authors.

Comment: Start with removing `t.string "author_id"` from `characters` _or_ change `belongs_to :author, through: :books` to `has_one :author`.

Comment: @TomLord Perhaps in a real world modeling--but for my learning purposes, this is what I'm sticking to right now.

Comment: @mudasobwa Your first solution errors with `ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through.` and the second doesn't make any change to the behavior

Comment: [`belongs_to through` relationships don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021322/belongs-to-through-associations). You should use [`has_one through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) instead, it'll work the same way.

Comment: As a side note, most rails developers I know never use `has_and_belongs_to_many`: It's almost always preferable to create an intermediary model and use `has_many through` (see: http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you probably want:

author.rb

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :books
  has_many :characters, -> {distinct}, through: :books

end
```

If on rails 4 you would use uniq instead of distinct.

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :author
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :characters, through: :book_characters
end
```

book_character.rb

```
class BookCharacter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :character
end
```

character.rb

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_characters
  has_many :books, through: :book_characters
  has_many :authors, through: :books
end
```

This actually accounts for all of the comments that you received and does so in a cleaner way. It allows for characters to have many authors, and avoids the messiness of the has_and_belongs_to_many relationships.

Furthermore, if you want, you can pretty much just pretend that the BookCharacter table doesn't exist. You can call `Book.characters.create(attributes)` and rails will create the intermediate object for you. However, the BookCharacter model could prove super useful in the future. You never know when you might want to differentiate between Harry Potter in book 6 and Harry Potter in book 7.